# Any good C++/C NNTP libs?

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-protocols, nntp

I came across some crusty and limited efforts awhile back but I was wondering if there was something truly functional that I missed, preferably in C++ but C is better than nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

W3Cs [libwww](http://www.w3.org/Library/) exposes a complete, standards compliant NNTP implementation.
It is cross platform and (*partially*) well documented.

- [User guide](http://www.w3.org/Library/User/Guide/)
- The API-of-interest: [WWWNews client API](http://www.w3.org/Library/User/Extrnals.html#WWWNews)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: At first scan it looks as good as anything I have come across.  Thanks.